# How to read exe file in binary code - C++

Tags: c++, programming-languages, binary

How can I make program in C++ that will read .exe or another file in binary code?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to read the binary data of a file? Do you want to parse an .exe file header? Do you want to display binary data?

Comment: I want to read file in binary code. For example I have program hello world and i want to read it in binary.

Comment: Does `ifstream` object with `binary` option fit? Or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("yourfile.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    ///
    in.read (buffer, buffer_size);
}
```

For a detailed example on how to read binary files in C++, see [this link](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall02/binio.html) or do your own googling.

Comment: And I'll add that you should use the unformatted input functions to read from such a stream.

Comment: @Martinho: The provided link explains that

Comment: And please, how looks like formated function? Please give me an example. And can I now use `in >> variable~ and than `cout <<variable`<

Comment: @Albatros: No, you can't. That's formatted input-output. If you're reading binary, you can just read bytes. See the site I linked for a detailed explanation

Comment: And, need I buffer size? And in that link are no informations about couting readed data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Regarding the `buffer`, I see `char buffer[100]` code line. Is the 100 kind standard practice?